# Hosted Blazor Pass Auth Token to API from Javascript Fetch Call

Tags: javascript, paypal, jwt, blazor, authorization

I have a hosted Blazor Webassembly app and I am trying to secure my Paypal API endpoint but it keeps showing that it is being called anonymously and failing with 401 Unauthorized.

I have a shopping cart Razor component with the Paypal buttons. They invoke the Paypal button Javascript. The CreateOrder javascript function calls my Blazor API Paypal controller CreateOrder endpoint. The endpoint is protected with the `[Authorize]` attribute. When it is not protected, I can hit the controller endpoint.

Here is my code.

```
export function Createorder(value, orderId) {
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            color: 'silver',
            tagline: 'false'
        },
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return fetch(`api/paypal/createorder/${orderId}`, {
                method: "post",
                credentials: 'include' // I recently added this
            }).then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    return response.json().then(error => { throw error; });
                }

                return response.json();
            }).then((order) => order.id)
                .catch(error => alert(error.message));
        },
        onApprove: (data, actions) => {
            return fetch(`api/paypal/captureorder/${data.orderID}/${orderId}`, {
                method: "post",
            }).then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    return response.json().then(error => { throw error; });
                }

                window.location.href = `PaymentSuccess/${orderId}`;
            }).catch(error => alert(error.message));
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        "AllowAll",
        b => b.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("https://localhost:7111"));

    options.AddPolicy("MyAllowCredentialsPolicy",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7111")
                   .AllowCredentials();
        });
});
```

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("createorder/{orderNumber}")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<CreateOrderResponse> CreateOrder([FromRoute] int orderNumber)

... not relevant
```

I read somewhere that when using the Javascript Fetch API, I need to add `credentials: 'include'` to the call and it should include my token credentials, but I don't think it is.

Here is what I am seeing in Chrome:
[image]

[image]

What am I missing?

**Solved**

I figured out the solution and wanted to show it. I changed the javascript to include the bearer token in the headers.

```
export function Createorder(value, orderId) {

    const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            color: 'silver',
            tagline: 'false'
        },
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return fetch(`api/paypal/createorder/${orderId}`, {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.replace(/"/g, ""),
                },                
            }).then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    return response.json().then(error => { throw error; });
                }

                return response.json();
            }).then((order) => order.id)
                .catch(error => alert(error.message));
        },
        onApprove: (data, actions) => {
            return fetch(`api/paypal/captureorder/${data.orderID}/${orderId}`, {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.replace(/"/g, ""),
                },
            }).then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    return response.json().then(error => { throw error; });
                }

                window.location.href = `PaymentSuccess/${orderId}`;
            }).catch(error => alert(error.message));
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
}
```

As part of troubleshooting the error, I had modified the cors policy in the API project. But after figuring out how to include my token, I tried changing the cors policy back to the way I had it originally, and it worked, so I didn't need to change it. Here is my cors policy now.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        "AllowAll",
        b => b.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin());
});
```